# SignalR WebSocket Closed with status code 1006 (no reason given) (only on the remote server after deployment)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I'm working with a project which combines angular app on a client-side and .net core 6 web API app on the server-side. To provide real-time communication between client and server on different browsers without reloading the page I use SignalR (with custom hubs of course) to track connections' Ids and send data to specific clients by connections' Ids which is stored in SQL server database after client connection and removed after client disconnection. On my local environment all works fine, but after deployment on hosting a websocket problem happened. On the first screenshot u can see no errors in my browser console in a couple of minutes after client connection and some data manipulations between client and server through hubs. On the second screenshot u can see the result of this data-manipulations between client and server but on the remote hosting server. I'm so confused about it, because this error happened only on remote server, locally websocket transfer type works as it expected.

[image]

[image]

Is it a hosting server error which needs to be resolved by hosting provider? Or this is my mistake?

I think there is a lot of questions with the same subject on the stack overflow, but I was searching for the right answer which can be a good solution for my problem, but... I can't find anything which can help me. Feel free to ask more info about signalR implementation if it needs to help me in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mikhail, I am currently facing this issue, do you know what is the fix for this issue ?

Comment: @Nothing nope :c

Comment: I also have this issue